# Python: instalar Pymaldi para lector de tarjetas

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe donde puedo descargar la librería pymaldi para Python?
Tengo que utilizarlo para acceder a un lector de tarjetas RDIF pero no consigo descargar la librería.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes descargar el módulo desde [el repositorio de pymaldi](https://github.com/skarcha/pymaldi) en GitHub.

Comment: Perdona @santiaguito pero acabo de leer que pymaldi no me vale porque solo sirve para lectores de tarjetas de tipo Kimaldi. ¿Alguna idea de como acceder a lector de tarjetas FEIG?

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/23899)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo pero es que no puede ser otra cosa más que un enlace ya que se pedía de donde descargar una librería. Otra cosa es si la pregunta es válida para SOes, a mi me parece que no.

Comment: @blonfu es verdad, pero entiendo que debería hacerse un comentario para este tipo de "respuestas"

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ok, supongo que se ha puesto automáticamente el texto al revisar, no?

Comment: @blonfu, correcto

Comment: Aunque la respuesta sea principlamente el enlace, trata de aportar más al indicar qué significa el enlace. Así, en caso que el enlace se rompa o el repositorio desaparezca, se podría buscar otra alternativa basada en la descripción indicada en la respuesta.